# Celery task subprocess: command not found (127)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, rabbitmq, celery

I have a `tasks.py` file that is trying to write the output of a `subprocess.check_output` command to a database (SQLAlchemy).

I was following a tutorial that directed to subclass the actual task so that closing the database connection would be more reliable, but for some reason now the `subprocess.check_output` command that is in that class is returning a 127 code...

Here's `tasks.py`

---

```
import subprocess
import os

from celery import Celery
from flask import flash
from db import db_session


app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

class SqlAlchemyTask(app.Task):
    abstract = True

    def after_return(self, status, retval, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
            db_session.remove()

@app.task(base=SqlAlchemyTask)
def update_db(var):
    #### these do not work ####
    repos = subprocess.check_output(['aplty', 'repo', 'list', '-raw'])
    snaps = subprocess.check_output(['aptly', 'snapshot', 'list', '-raw'])

    repos2 = repos.splitlines()
    snaps2 = snaps.splitlines()

    for x in repos2:
            repo = Repos(x)
            db.session.add(repo)
            db.session.commit()
    for y in snaps2:
            snap = Snaps(y)
            db.session.add(snap)
            db.session.commit()

### UPLOAD TASKS
@app.task(track_started=True)
def move_files(upRepo, filedir):
    if subprocess.check_call(['aptly', 'repo', 'add', upRepo, filedir]) == 0:
            pass
    else:
            subprocess.check_call('false')
            subprocess.check_call('false')


### SNAPSHOT TASKS
@app.task(track_started=True)
def make_snapshot(existRepoName, snapName):
    if subprocess.check_call(['aptly', 'snapshot', 'create', snapName, 'from', 'repo', existRepoName]) == 0:
            pass
    else:
            subprocess.check_call('false')
```

---

The `update_db` task is the one where the `subprocess.check_output` commands give the return of 127, which is odd because the `move_files` and `make_snapshot` run the same command with just different arguments and they work fine. Also, running the `update_db` commands from the interpreter work fine as well! If I removed the class `SqlAlchemyTask` and the corresponding task `update_db` then this `tasks.py` file work completely fine.

Any help on fixing this would be great!
Thanks!